# Create the right pom.xml for LWJGL and Slick Project (Maven)

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick

Can somebody tell me whats wrong with my pom.xml file?

At this point I get this error if I start my *.jar file:

```
C:\Users\Michael\git\freezing-robot\target>java -jar freezing-robot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/newdawn/slick/BasicGame
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

And my pom file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.devnetik.freezing-robot</groupId>
    <artifactId>freezing-robot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>freezing-robot</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <package.name>de.devnetik.freezing_robot</package.name>
        <main.class>${package.name}.App</main.class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <natives.version>0.0.6</natives.version>
        <lwjgl.version>2.8.2</lwjgl.version>
        <slick.version>274</slick.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mavenNatives</id>
            <name>Maven Natives Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavennatives.googlecode.com/svn/repo</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>slick</id>
            <name>slick</name>
            <url>http://slick.cokeandcode.com/mavenrepo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.mavennatives</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-nativedependencies-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${natives.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpacknatives</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>

                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                            <packageName>${package.name}</packageName>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>slick</groupId>
            <artifactId>slick</artifactId>
            <version>${slick.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I try to start the application from eclipse through "play" ill get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
    at de.devnetik.freezing_robot.App.main(App.java:30)
```

And at least this is my project folder structure:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: hmm ill try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, there's no LWJGL in your java library path. See [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14085/no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path) for that.

For setting that up in Eclipse you want to add the `-Djava.library.path="your_path"` part into the VM arguments field found in the debug/build section in the project settings in eclipse. The `"your_path"` part should point to the native libraries for LWJGL (native to whatever system you're working on be it Windows, Mac or Linux).

Comment: awesome its working. thank you. i would vote up but i cant :D so you have to wait a bit